# How convert color codes generated from threejs THREE.MeshPhongMaterial to HEX

Tags: javascript, three.js, color-codes

When used like thisin threejs

```
const INITIAL_BODY_MTL = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x374047, shininess: 10 });
```

It is creating a object with changing color codes

```
 {
  "color": {
    "r": 0.21568627450980393,
    "g": 0.25098039215686274,
    "b": 0.2784313725490196
  },
```

How to change that to normal HEX.
As I searched and found those are float64 format
But I am unable to convert to HEX using **Javascript**

Comment: Just from the documentation: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Color.getHex

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you for answer, how to apply colo object to to get hex value

Comment: `var hexVal = INITIAL_BODY_MTL.color.getHex()`, I think. But it's not clear want your goal is.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you got it by`var hexVal = INITIAL_BODY_MTL.color.getHex().toString(16);`

Comment: There's also that method: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Color.getHexString

Comment: @prisoner849 working fine thank you.